# Keeping a running total in a subquery and returning a count - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a sub query that keeps a running total and returns a count of the number of times the running total is above 4.99.

```
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
|    Date    | Occurrence | Running Total | Count |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
| 5/21/2017  |      0.25  |          6.75 |     6 |
| 5/9/2017   |         1  |           6.5 |     5 |
| 5/8/2017   |         0  |           5.5 |     4 |
| 4/17/2017  |      0.25  |           5.5 |     3 |
| 3/15/2017  |      0.25  |          5.25 |     2 |
| 2/15/2017  |      0.25  |             5 |     1 |
| 1/6/2017   |      0.25  |          4.75 |       |
| 12/19/2016 |      0.25  |           4.5 |       |
| 12/14/2016 |      0.25  |          4.25 |       |
| 12/6/2016  |      0.25  |             4 |       |
| 12/2/2016  |         1  |          3.75 |       |
| 12/1/2016  |         1  |          2.75 |       |
| 11/17/2016 |      0.25  |          1.75 |       |
| 10/17/2016 |         1  |           1.5 |       |
| 9/29/2016  |      0.25  |           0.5 |       |
| 9/28/2016  |      0.25  |          0.25 |       |
| 9/13/2016  |         0  |             0 |       |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Based on the example data that I provided I would like the query to return the int of 6.

The table that I have has two columns which include date and occurrence.

Example of a select statement:

```
SELECT [Date], [Occurrence]
FROM TimeUsage
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
```

I would like to use this code within another SQL query.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: and here's a EASY tool to use: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function to calculate the Running Total

```
SELECT COUNT(RunningTotal) 
FROM (
     SELECT SUM(Occurance) OVER (ORDER BY Date) as RunningTotal
     FROM YourTable
) as T
WHERE RunningTotal > 4.99
```

Comment: Order by date desc (after where not in window function)

Comment: @xQbert Op doesn't want a list just the total of element `> 4.99` in this case `6`

Comment: OOps.  gotcha. withdrawn

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!